# In Great Britain, did the Liberal Unionists and Conservatives ever compete for the same seats in elections?

Tags: political-history, united-kingdom, election

The Liberal Unionists fought elections against the Liberals. Did Liberal Unionists ever stand in the same seats as Conservatives too, or did they have a pact right from the beginning?

Comment: This would be clearer and easier to answer if you specified what country you were talking about.  It could be (at least) United Kingdom or Canada.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.** There was at least one case from the very start, during the [1886 election](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_general_election,_1886). This was of course the birth year of the [Liberal Unionists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Unionist_Party), and they formed a close alliance with the [Conservatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_Party_%28UK%29) thereafter.

> Despite the Conservative Chief Whip's promise, three of the 93 were opposed by Conservatives, and two lost their seats to Conservatives. Those two included the **one Liberal Unionist** who was opposed by a Gladstonian Liberal as well, who finished bottom of the poll.
>
> **<sub>Douglas, Roy. Liberals: *A History of the Liberal and Liberal Democratic Parties*. London: Hambledon and London, 2005.</sub>**

There was *kind of* a pact from the very start. When the Liberal Prime Minister [William Ewart Gladstone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Ewart_Gladstone) attempted to pass the [First Home Rule Bill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_of_Ireland_Bill_1886), the Conservatives sough support from within Liberal ranks. Liberal members who voted against the [Second Reading](http://www.parliament.uk/about/how/laws/passage-bill/lords/lrds-commons-second-reading/) of the bill were promised non-competition, and 93 of them sided with the Conservatives in the vote.